# ReactNative: Element appearing on Top but wont trigger onPress

Tags: react-native, expo

I have created a dropdown. Its elements appearing on top of body, however, when I press them, it actually triggers onPress on elements underneath them.

You guys can see the issue:
[image]

Code for the Dropdown is:

```
            <View style={[styles.container]}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.main_container} onPress={this.animate}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.selectedCategoryText}</Text>
                <Image style={styles.image}
                    source={require('../../assets/icons/dropdown.png')}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View >
                <Animated.View style={[styles.animated_container,{opacity: this.opacity, zIndex:1, elevation:1}]}>
                    <ScrollView style={{height:60}}>
                        { this.data.map( (item, i)=>
                             <TouchableOpacity 
                                style={{}}
                                disabled={false} 
                                key={i} 
                                onPress={()=>this.selectItem(i)}>
                                    <Text style={styles.item_text}>{item} </Text>
                              </TouchableOpacity>
                             )}
                    </ScrollView>
                </Animated.View>

            </View>
        </View>
```

I have applied absolute positioning on the animated view which displays the dropdown items.

```
animated_container:{
    backgroundColor: colors.secondaryWhiteColor,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '100%',
    width: '100%', height: 70
}
```

Comment: try adding `display: block` and `z-index:9999999` (to verify). Alternatively, add some padding to see if that helps.

Comment: React native doesn't supports block https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#display. zIndex is alsonot making any effect :(

Comment: There is a react-native bug on Android where touch events do not work for elements which are absolutely positioned outside their container element

Comment: I have managed to know the source of the problem. DrawerNavigator from React.Navigation is doing something. If I remove the screen containing dropdown from the DrawerNavigator, then it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to know the source of the problem, however I still don't know what exactly is the problem. DrawerNavigator from React.Navigation is doing something. If I remove the screen containing dropdown from the DrawerNavigator, then it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

try to use touchable opacity from gesture handler not react native